# Using git commit count and commit hash as version in artifact generated by Maven

Tags: git, maven, versioning

I've seen so many (answered) questions about using git commit hash as suffix in the version generated when releasing library. But I can't find any link that describe using commit count in combination of commit hash.

The version format that I'm looking for is `<commit count>-<commit hash>` for Java library built using Maven.

Is there any existing Maven plugin that can generate that format?

Comment: Using a git hash as version for a lib is a bad idea because you can not determine which version is newer than another one... Also using a suffix does not make sense.. using semantical version is a much better approach. Let me say what would be the difference between `1.1.0-5a675ea3` and `1.1.0-9a6f5423` ? Better would be having `1.1.0` and `1.1.1` and `1.1.2`...

Comment: @khmarbaise Not sure if you read the entire question. What I wanted is not only git-hash, but including git-commit-count. The idea is the git-commit-count is always increasing forever, that alone will replace the whole semver because in corporate environment, nobody cares whether it's 1.1.0 upgraded to 1.2.0 or 1.1.1 or even 2.0.0, What matter is the next version must be *higher* version. That'll be achieved with commit-count.
The commit-hash is to determine which commit was the version taken from.

Comment: You're assuming every version is backwards compatible. Semver addresses the case when they're not.

Comment: @Alex I'm assuming in corporate environment where what we produce is internally used within our own application. The library is also produced by the same maven build tool and within single big git repository. There is only 1 repository for the entire organization. Backward compatibility is not an issue in my environment.

Comment: `What matter is the next version must be higher version.` than the cleanest way is to use semver.. makes everything clear...  As already mentioned the compatibility is the important part...otherwise you will break code...

Comment: Git commit counts don't necessarily *always* increase, but if you use Git in a carefully controlled and prescribed fashion, they will. Just watch out for someone who likes to rewrite history to collapse a bunch of small commits together. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your maven file:

```
<build>
<finalName>${project.name}-${git.total.commit.count}-${git.commit.id.abbrev}</finalName>
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>io.github.git-commit-id</groupId>
        <artifactId>git-commit-id-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <goals>
                    <goal>revision</goal>
                </goals>
                <phase>initialize</phase>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
```

See [git-commit-id-maven-plugin](https://github.com/git-commit-id/git-commit-id-maven-plugin/blob/master/docs/using-the-plugin.md).

Once again, I want to point out that this is a bad library version and I wouldn't be happy consuming it. You talk about a single git repo in your company but that's irrelevant as it says nothing about the consumers of your library. You're probably building an "application" (no consumers) while referring to it as a "library".

Comment: Thanks… this is what I’m looking for. I can’t dwell into the detail why I need this, but I know the diff between application and library.
Thanks again